# ASP.NET Web API 2 windows identity not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I created a very simple example Web API 2 app at http://www.windward.net/temp/TestWindowsAuthentication.zip that is set to use windows identity. But what returns, when running under VisualStudio 2013 on my system (logged in as a domain user) is (url: localhost:6596/about):

```
{
PrincipalName: "",
PrincipalIsAuthenticated: false,
UserName: "",
UserIsAuthenticated: false
}
```

What else do I need to do?

Also, for the case where a user is not logged in to the domain, what do I need to do so it prompts them for a login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set project properties to enable windows auth and disable anonymous auth.

[image]

BTW, you'd better upgrade to web api 2 RTM.

Comment: Where can I download the RTM build? I did a search and couldn't find it.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads for download VS 2013. You can also upgrade your project in nuget to RTM packages.

Comment: I spent far too long mucking around trying to find a solution to this problem after seeing this post.  You have to select the project file and hit F4 to access this pane.  Right clicking and going to the regular properties does not allow you to set these variables.  Setting them in your ApplicationHostConfig is not enough. The <authentication mode="Windows" /> tag in your web.config is not enough either.